# How can I add groups to my listview?

Tags: android, listview

I populate a list view using this adapter and data from a webservice

```
final SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, items,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2,
                new String[] {"id", "description"},
                new int[] {android.R.id.text1,
                        android.R.id.text2});
        final ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.recordView);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

I need to add groups similar to https://code.google.com/archive/p/android-amazing-listview/

But It seems like amazinglistview isn't usable anymore. Most tutorials I'm finding are vague and from years and years ago.

Comment: You need to implement baseadapter: Checkout this youtube video. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EnG5ZIVfki8                                            Good tutorial: http://javatechig.com/android/listview-with-section-header-in-android

Comment: that is custom library. You need to impleted that

Comment: @Pravin it doesn't look like a custom library?

Comment: @YasinYaqoobi I'll check that out now, odd I never found it before

Comment: @AlexF11 https://github.com/yukuku/android-amazing-listview look this URL

Comment: @YasinYaqoobi I followed that tutorial. I'll need to modify the xml snippets so I can style them properly and modify the adapter to accept multiple lines of text but it should work. Thank you.